# How to solve a black screen with a dash error after booting my asus e205-se with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: boot, command-line

It was booting just fine then after restarting the computer it get stuck to that dummy black scree with a little dash at the top left corner. Am stuck in the middle of something here guys help me out

Comment: Is there a swap partition or file? Ubuntu will (usually) not boot without it.

Comment: I figured it was because of the graphics updates something to do with the nvidia gcard. Thanks by the way guys